# Extract text between all tags on multiple XML files and copy the extracted text to a csv file

Tags: python, csv, parsing, beautifulsoup, extract

I would like to know how can I extract the text beetween all the tags inside multiples XML documents, get the filename and then write this info to a CSV file.

For the moment I got this :

```
import csv
import glob
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

dataExtracted = []
for filename in glob.glob(r'*.xml'):
    with open(filename, 'r') as f_in:
        soup = BeautifulSoup(f_in.read(), 'lxml')
    print(filename)
    for i in soup.findAll(text=True):
        print(i)
        dataExtracted.append([filename, i.get_text()])

with open('data.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    csv_writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',', quotechar='"', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    for row in dataExtracted:
        csv_writer.writerow(row)
```

I got this error when I try to run it :

```
AttributeError: 'NavigableString' object has no attribute 'get_text'
```

I've tried to add this :

```
for i in soup.findAll(text=True):
        try:
            print(i)
            dataExtracted.append([filename, i.get_text(strip=True)])
        except NavigableString:
            pass
```

But now i got this error :

```
catching classes that do not inherit from BaseException is not allowed
```

So I think I'm not handling the error correctly.

Any ideas on how I should handle this problem ?

Answer (score 0):

You can try to test if your element is a navigable string by adding this in your for loop, and then ignore it if it is by adding the continue statement:

```py
for i in soup.findAll(text=True):
    if isinstance(i, NavigableString):
        continue
    print(filename)
    dataExtracted.append([filename, i.get_text()])
```

Apparently, depending on your BeautifulSoup version you could have what you wrote working:
"As of Beautiful Soup version 4.10.0, you can call get_text(), .strings, or .stripped_strings on a NavigableString object. It will either return the object itself, or nothing, so the only reason to do this is when you’re iterating over a mixed list."

4.10.0 is the latest version on Pypi